# trouble with array_merge, serialize and unserialize in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I have to do this:

1. take an associative array and insert it into a field in my database so I can re-use it as associative array. [DONE with serialize($associativeArray)]
2. take the associative array from the database and view as array. [DONE with `unserialize($arraySerializedBefore)`]
3. Merge an array already in the database (serialized) with an array just created.

For example:

```
Array 
( 
  [1] => 'nanananana,lol,',
  [2] => 'laaaaalalalala,asd,',
  [3] => 'r0tfl,lmfao,ahah,'
)
```

Second array to merge with the first:

```
Array 
( 
  [1] => 'dunnoWhat,write,',
  [3] => 'hello,wooorld,'
)
```

So I need a final array like this:

```
Array 
( 
  [1] => 'nanananana,lol,\N,dunnoWhat,write,',
  [2] => 'laaaaalalalala,asd,',
  [3] => 'r0tfl,lmfao,ahah,\N,hello,wooorld,'
)
```

If you see it merge it using the key, if they have the same key, it adds a "\n" to go in a new line (the same of BR tag...it's only an example) and after it add the string of the second array correspondent to the key. However if you don't understand watch the example and you will.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that there are keys in the second array that do not occur in the first array? The example doesn't reject that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just was wondering if it's possible to resolve with one functional block (like functional programming). It is:

```
$foo = [
   0 => "test zero",
   1 => "test one",
   2 => "test two",
   3 => "test three"
];

$bar = [
   1 => "test four",
   5 => "test five",
   3 => "test six",
   4 => "test seven"
];

$result = 
   array_diff_key($foo, $bar)
   +
   array_combine(
      $y = array_keys(array_intersect_key($foo, $bar)), 
      array_map(function($x) use ($foo, $bar)
      {
         return $foo[$x]."\n".$bar[$x];
      }, $y)
   )
   +
   array_diff_key($bar, $foo);
```

Comment: Seems like a 5 different array functions overkill ;)

Comment: _"I just was wondering if it's possible to resolve with one functional block"_

Comment: @AlmaDo You missed the commas, also your keys are not in order.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger What commas?

Comment: I didn't miss commas since _'it adds a "\n" to go in a new line'_ said by OP. And I didn't miss order since nothing said about that (and it isn't obvious what it should be when merging arrays with different keys)

Comment: @AlmaDo The output seems different from yours. Maybe you assumed a few stuff, just saying.

Comment: i'm using it but how to order the keys? with sort or asort it use also the key number 0 and i don't want it!

Comment: You need to specify your ordering. I.e. what should be order in result (especially if there will be some missing keys)

Comment: could you give me an example? If i need to order this: (i write only the keys) 3,5,1,2 or 3,4,1,2

Comment: You need to specify what do you mean "order". What should be result?

Comment: 1,2,3,5 - 1,2,3,4. With `array_multisort` it gives me results with the 0, so 0,1,2,3 - 0,1,2,3. I don't wanna that. I don't wanna the number 0. :)

Comment: anybody have found anything?

Comment: So you want keys, starting from 1, not 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the second array using a `foreach` and match its keys with the one with the first array and if match found, Update the first array by concatenation.

```
<?php

$arr1=Array(1 => 'nanananana,lol,',2 => 'laaaaalalalala,asd,',3 => 'r0tfl,lmfao,ahah,');
$arr2=Array(1 => 'dunnoWhat,write,',3 => 'hello,wooorld,');

$i=min(array_keys($arr1));
foreach($arr2 as $k=>$val)
{
    if(array_key_exists($k,$arr1))
    {
    $arr1[$k].='\N, '.$val;
    }

}
print_r($arr1);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [1] => nanananana,lol,\N, dunnoWhat,write,
    [2] => laaaaalalalala,asd,
    [3] => r0tfl,lmfao,ahah,\N, hello,wooorld,
)
```

Comment: This will fail, btw - if there are non-existent keys (like in my sample). Compare this [invalid](http://3v4l.org/cK95W) result and this [expected](http://3v4l.org/uOeKS) result

Comment: @AlmaDo, How is that result `invalid` ? OP wants the first array to be updated if the key of it matches with the key of the second array.

Comment: Well, it is invalid in case of non-existent keys. OP didn't mentioned if they may be. Thus, I found this case as invalid behavior. So if such case won't appear, code above will work fine

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, Alma Do is right, if i use in the second array the key 5 (using my example), it gives me error. How to? the example of Alma Do is not so good, 'cause it doesn't sort the final array. (5 is not before 4..)